# Parse the string of comma delimited numbers into respective object properties

Tags: javascript

How to make an object from a string of numbers?

Example:

```
const coor = "255, 255, 0, 4";
```

To:

```
const myObj = {
 x: 255,
 y: 255,
 width: 0,
 height: 4,
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
const coor = "255, 255, 0, 4";


const [x,y,width,height] = coor.split(', ');

const myObj = {
  x: Number(x),
  y: Number(y),
  width: Number(width),
  height: Number(height)
};

console.log(myObj);
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use [destructuring syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) together with [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) (to cast number-like strings to `Number`):

```js
const coor = "255, 255, 0, 4",
      [x, y, width, height] = coor.split(', ').map(Number),
      
      obj = {x, y, width, height}
      
console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var res = coor.split(", ");

const myObj = {
    x: Number(res[0]),
    y: Number(res[1]),
    width: Number(res[2]),
    height: Number(res[3]),
}
```